# Jquery plugin to Sort a table made of <div>

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to make sortable a table made with div and diplay table using some jquery plugin.

I can modify my table but i can't use html  tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table made out of a table. Tables have their place in HTML, which is to show tabular data.

Check out http://tablesorter.com for an easy plugin:

HTML Example:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

jQuery Example:

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
```

Comment: The point is not that i don't like html tables. When i tell you that i can modify my table but i can't use html table tags is becaus that is the way things are.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can do anything you want with the DOM, including converting divs to tables. Not saying you should, but don't say you can't.

Comment: Do you have some answer you think i should try given the specific circumstances expressed in the question? If you have some practical way to solve this, i appreciate the help...

Comment: First I need to see your HTML. Can you update your question to include it please?

Comment: HTML tables have their place, but there are circumstances when they are not an option. By example, you cannot embed `<form>` tags within tables for per row saving (which otherwise requires sending all the rows to the server to save them all at once or discarding a lot of data to save a single row).

Comment: Sure you can. Just because it's non-compliant doesn't mean you can't do it.